# Capture true/false result of an operation

Tags: ruby

My code looks like this, and it works:

```
if Target.find_by_shrunk(params[:shrunk])
  @target = Target.find_by_shrunk(params[:shrunk])
else
  # do something else
end
```

`Target::find_by_shrunk(params[:shrunk])` gets called twice. In  order to avoid this, I want to run `Target.find_by_shrunk(params[:shrunk])` once, catch the `true`/`false` result, then use that variable in the conditional statement. I tried doing this:

```
does_it_exist = (this_target = Target.find_by_shrunk(params[:shrunk]))
if does_it_exist
  @target = this_target
else
  # do something else
end
```

But unfortunately that doesn't do what I want it to.

How do I simultaneously perform an assignment, and somehow capture the true/false result of performing that assignment, so i don't have to run the same (expensive) piece of code twice in a row?

Comment: weird, the second chunk of code should work.  You can write it a little cleaner but should be working.

Comment: In your second code, assignment to `does_it_exist` is redundant. It is exactly the same as `this_target`.

Comment: It's entirely possible I had the idea right and made some kind of syntax error elsewhere that made it break. After rewriting it to look like Ricardo Panaggio's answer, it worked. As I said, I'm a bit of a ruby noob, so I think it's entirely possible I had done something wrong elsewhere that broke it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do

```
unless @target = Target.find_by_shrunk(params[:shrunk])
  # do something else
end
```

`unless` is the same as `if not`. An attribution returns the value attributed, and if it's different from `nil` and `false`, it evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Yes! That worked perfectly. Thank you so much. You just made that query run twice as fast!

Comment: Now, I don't fully understand why this worked and what I tried didn't work... but one little piece of knowledge at a time lol. Thanks again.

Comment: Making your second code chunk clearer (for me), it seems it should work.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
if this_target = Target.find_by_shrunk(params[:shrunk])
  @target = this_target   
else
  #do something else
end
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
something_else unless @target = Target.find_by_shrunk(params[:shrunk])
```

or, if you need the positive

```
do_something if @target = Target.find_by_shrunk(params[:shrunk])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could initialise @target to nil, so when you come to test it, if it's nil, call find_by_shrunk and assign the result to @target.